# Centerline Addressing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, maps, address

I work for a local government and am in the process of cleaning up / updating addressing data. I have a MXD for the purpose of 'point addressing' and 'centerline addressing'.

It is the centerline data that I am concerned about. My workflow can either consists of "rolling my sleeves up" and manually digitizing the data or what I wan to do is find an automated way to complete this work.

The city has theoretical and actual address ranges. The issue is that the actual address range data is filled in the theoretical fields, thus the theoretical address ranges are wrong.

What I am trying to accomplish is writing or using attribute assistant to identify all actual address records that are Null and copy the records from the theoretical address fields to the actual address fields. Further since the theoretical address fields are partially wrong I would like to have a TRIGGER event that if the process where the Null values are converted = TRUE then the last two digit of the Left_to and Right_to fields for the theoretical addresses will be changed to -98 and 99.

Example:

Actual Address Range:
Left side of road = 800-832 ; Right side of road = 801-835

Theoretical Address Range:

Left side of road = 800-898 ; Right side of road = 801-899

[image]

Comment: 1. `Select By Attribute` -> `Act_LeftFrom is null`, 2. `Calculate field` on `Act_LeftFrom` -> `[LeftFrom]`

Comment: are those fields text or integers .. if they are integers then ... Select By Attribute -> Act_LeftTo is null ... Calculate on Act_LeftTo = int(LeftTo/100)+98